# Anyone know how I can get FCL style initialisation syntax for c# types?

Tags: c#, types

Instead of writing

```
 int i = new int();
 i = 7;
```

One can write

```
int i = 7;
```

Is there a way I can get that style of initialisation for my own types?

```
MyType mt = xyz;
```

Comment: I thought that did initialise `MyType`.

Comment: It's nothing. But say, for example, I wanted to write a custom string class - String2. Could I design it such that it initialises with String2 s2 = "yo". Or am I stuck with making it look like String2 s2 = new String2("yo") or some such verbosity. I'm just looking for the brevity FCL primitives use in my own types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can come is by creating implicit conversions on your type. For example:

```
public class Unit
{
  public static implicit operator Unit( string val )
  {
     return Unit.Parse( val );
  }

  public static Unit Parse( string unitString )
  {
    // parsing magic goes here
  }
}
```

This would enable you to do something like this:

```
Unit width = "150px";
var width = Unit.Parse("150px"); // equivalent to previous line
```

Note that you cannot introduce new syntax; this would be **impossible** to implement:

```
Unit width = 150px;
```

since `150px` does not represent a valid value type.

Note that implicit casting can get you into trouble in weird ways so don't over do it. Support implicit casting only to and from types that you're really going to need.

Alternatively, if you're using C# compiler 3.5 or up you can also use inline initialization which is more verbose but also more explicit:

```
Unit with = new { Value=150, UnitType=Units.Pixel };
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer is "no you can't". You're always going to hide a `new` somewhere.

In your specific case you could do some trick with implicit conversions like this:

```
class String2 {
    private readonly string WrappedString;

    public String2(string wrappedString) {
        this.WrappedString = "my modified " + wrappedString ;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.WrappedString; 
    }

   // the "magic" is here: the string you assign to String2 gets implicitly
   // converted to a String2 
    public static implicit operator String2(string wrappedString) {
        return new String2(wrappedString);
    }
}
```

that enables you to do:

```
String2 test = "test";
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString()); // writes: "my modified test" to the Console
```

but you get the "new" hidden in the implicit conversion anyway.

Another approach which may be more general and lands you not too far from the syntax you want is through extension methods:

```
   static class StringExtensions {
        public static String2 ToString2(this string that) {return new String2(that);}
   }
```

with that in scope, you can do this:

```
var test2="anothertest".ToString2();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is implicit conversions what MSFT use to allow quick initialisation for int/byte/string etc?

Comment: No it's not. Primitive types, like int/byte/string, get a special treatment from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example in your comment you could add an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) to the type.

Note that doing this is generally not recommended because it makes your code less readable. For example, something like `String2 s2 = new String2("yo")` is completely explicit about what is happening; not so with something like `String2 s2 = "yo"`.

```
String2 s2 = "yo";

// ...

public sealed class String2
{
    public readonly string _value;
    public string Value { get { return _value; } }

    public String2(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator String2(string value)
    {
        return new String2(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's rad!  I like it. I don't mind that it's less "readable" as it's for my own code and not a library. What is readable anyway? Apart from the fact that something works because Microsoft allowed it to work? Personally, I get confused about why certain types are allowed to be initialised with syntactic sugar and others aren't. You have to dig into the framework to work out how int and string are implemented with syntactic sugar, it's not made explicit to us.  For my own types it's explicit to me if I wrote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through implicit cast operators.

Here's an article that describes the concept: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Csharp_implicit_operator.aspx